# If B is an upper bound of $f(x)$ in some neighborhood of $a$, does it follow that $\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow a} f(x) \le B$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, upper-lower-bounds

Intuitively it makes sense just from looking at a graph. If the function is bounded above by some upper bound in the neighborhood of $a$, then the limit at $a$ will naturally be bounded above by the same bound. However, I'm struggling to use the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of a limit to actually prove this.

Comment: Your function $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Suggestion: Assume the limit $L$ is greater than $B$ and then use $\varepsilon=1/2(B-L)$ and go for a contradiction.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a shot

Comment: @thewatcher continuity not needed, only that limit exists.

Comment: @coffeemath I think I got it using $\epsilon = B - L$. Is the 1/2 necessary?

Comment: The 1/2 isn't necessary as the answer of amsmath shows. I just thought it *might* be easier.

Answer (score 3):

Let $b := \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x) - b|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$, $x\neq a$. Hence,
$|b| = |b-f(x)+f(x)|\le |b-f(x)|+|f(x)|\le \epsilon + B$ for $|x-a|<\delta$. Letting $\epsilon\to 0$ yields the claim.

Comment: This results in $\vert b\vert \le B$, rather than $b \le B$. Is this a problem?

Comment: Not a problem since $b \le |b|$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the limit is $L$. Fix an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. The definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ implies that there is a $\delta_1>0$ satisfying
$$|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\text{ for every }x\in\text{dom}[f]\text{ with }0<|x-a|<\delta_1$$
or
$$L-\varepsilon<f(x)<L+\varepsilon\text{ for every }x\in\text{dom}[f]\text{ with }0<|x-a|<\delta_1$$
We're given that $B$ is an upper bound of $f$ in some neighborhood of $a$, so there's a $\delta_2>0$ satisfying
$$f(x)\leq B\text{ for every }x\in(a-\delta_2,a+\delta_2)$$
It follows that for every $x\in\text{dom}[f]$, if $0<|x-a|<\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, then $0<|x-a|<\delta_1$ and $0<|x-a|<\delta_2$, so
$$L-\varepsilon<f(x)<L+\varepsilon\text{ and }f(x)\leq B$$
and consequently $L-\varepsilon<B$.

We fixed $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrarily, so the preceding argument can be applied to any any positive real number. This implies that $L-\varepsilon<B$ is true for every $\varepsilon>0$, so $L\leq B$.